# How to make custom textview in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, textview

[image]

i am developing layout.i developed drawable for this layout.but text is not adjust in this view.anyone tell me about library are anyother guidlines please provide me.thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android there is a method [setRotation(float)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation%28float%29), which you can use it

```
textview.setRotation(float);
```

> NOTE: this method was added in **API  11**

so if you want to support it you can use this

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {

    RotateAnimation animation = new RotateAnimation(oldAngel, newAngel);
    animation.setDuration(100);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    watermarkText.startAnimation(animation);
} else {

    watermarkText.setRotation(progress);
}
```

#### EDIT: Here's my solution:

[image]

Here's my full `activity_main.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:text="HP  EliteBook 1212x"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"

            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/laptop"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="175dp"
            android:layout_height="175dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/triangle"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/prices"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:rotation="-45.0"
            android:textAlignment="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/old_price"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="200$"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/new_price"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/old_price"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="400$"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

For creating triangle, create `triangle.xml` file in this directory:

```
your_app_name/app/src/main/res/drawable
```

and as content put this code:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-45"
            android:toDegrees="0"
            android:pivotX="150%"
            android:pivotY="20%" >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle" >
                <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

In your Java `MainActivity` class put:

```
    TextView oldPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.old_price);
    oldPrice.setPaintFlags(oldPrice.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

to add to your old price text **strike-through** effect.

If you have a question, please free to ask.
Hope it help

Comment: 1543 thanks.. but text is not animation my requirement.. my requirement is text is fixed..

Comment: I've already added my solution, hope it help

Comment: thanks bro..it is working....

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do is:

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rotated"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#AA000F"
        android:rotation="-50"
        android:text="ABC"
        android:textColor="#44CC44"
        android:textSize="32sp" />
```

You can do it with the other layouts or edittexts too

Comment: this is without animations... Simple as u required

Comment: i know but it is not answer according my question..

Comment: you have to use label for this type text

Comment: This make the text exactly tilted as you wanted. Actually you've to create a layout and then add both the text view in that layout ... and make them tilted...

Answer (score 1):

[image]There is property in TextView . You can rotate by as per your requirement
Please refer below example for reference

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/won_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:rotation="-45"
                android:text="@string/won"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="34sp" />
```