# Trianlge at topright corner with image inside in android

Tags: android, shapes

I need triangle shape at top right corner with image inside. Triangle shape should be dynamic depend on parent layout.

**This is currently looks.**

[image]

I have looked into may post and created upto above image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@drawable/triangle_shape"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/more_hdpi"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
                />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**triangle_shape.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-45"
            android:toDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="0%"
                android:pivotY="-45%" >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle" >
                <stroke android:color="@color/yellow" android:width="10dp"/>
                <solid
                    android:color="@color/yellow" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
  </layer-list>
```

But, as you see i have fix width and image look at bottom of the shape i need it in center of the shape like:

**This is what i want.**

[image]

when i look in android studio deign view it loos like height and width is double of the shape. That is because shape is actually  rectangle and it is rotated.

**Currently looks in android studio preview.**

[image]

I look in many post like **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35079966/android-how-to-add-a-triangle-shape-in-the-right-top-button-corner)** but didn't get solution in any. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: so what is your problem actually?

Comment: @pskink I need image in center of the shape and shape should not have fixed width. Currently you can see that layout is almost double in size. I have posted my efforts

Comment: so what width do you want? on your "This is what i want." image the width is 2x bigger than image width, is it correct?

Comment: @pskink Main problem is to center the image inside shape. And currently you can check relative layout height and width is 2X. I need it to exact size of shape

Comment: `layout_centerVerticallayout_centerVertical` ?

Comment: @pskink That's already done. Check my current code.

Comment: if you use `layout_centerVerticallayout_centerVertical` then it centers vertically inside parent view (`RelativeLayout`), thats why your image is placed around the bottom of your triangle

Comment: @pskink Yes that was the main issue

Comment: You can use an Image with yellow triangular background instead of making a shape

Comment: @AvaniNagar I don't want to use image that's why i have created shape.

Comment: @ketan do you have the solution?

Comment: @HaiHack As i remembered. I used image with icon.

Comment: yeah, I use ImageView instead of drawable eventually

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check but you can try by putting both triangle and your image in a particular relative layout with gravity  center. This may help you, let me know if this would do.

Comment: I have done that and it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwUd6.png